# How can I get link that contains next?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get only **a** tag which contains **"next"** and this is what I applied

```
response.xpath('//a[text()="next"]')
```

But it's returning empty. Here is the details: Please tell me what's wrong I'm doing?

```
<div class="pagination">
<a href="/lists?page=2">2</a>
<a href="/lists?page=3">3</a>
<a href="/lists?page=4">4</a>
<a href="/lists?page=5">5</a>
<a href="/lists?page=6">6</a>
<a href="/lists?page=7">7</a>
<a href="/lists?page=8">8</a>
<a href="/lists?page=9">9</a>...
<a href="/lists?page=510">510</a>
<a href="/lists?page=511">511</a>
<a href="/lists?page=2">next <i class="fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
```

Comment: Try `contains`. See https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#learning-css-and-xpath for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "next")]/@href')
```